# Class not found (0)

Tags: php, битрикс

> [Error]  Class 'Has\Module\CompanyPoints' not found (0)

```
<?
namespace Has\Module;

use \Bitrix\Main\Config\Option;
use \Bitrix\Main\UserTable as User;

class CompanyPoints{
      function func(){return true;}
}
?>
```

test.php

```
 use \Bitrix\Main\Loader;

    use \Bitrix\Main\Application;

    use \Has\Module\CompanyPoints;

    Loader::includeModule("Module");

    $addresses=CompanyPoints::func();
```

вылезает ошибка, почему?

Comment: Автолоадер не в курсе про эти неймспейсы?

Comment: во-первых, автолодер я не нашла ни в папке локал, ни в папке битрикс
Но, если обратиться к методу другого класса другого файла, то все работает

Comment: @u_mulder, 
если обратиться к методу другого класса другого файла, то все работает)
если я переименую файл другого класса, то и другой класс перестает работать...
Значит, где то автозагрузчик, а где найти не могу

Comment: Автолоадер находится в файле include.php в каждом модуле.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если это свой модуль то в include нужно загрузить вашу библиотеку. Или в init.php

```
    CModule::AddAutoloadClasses(
        '', // не указываем имя модуля
        array(
           // ключ - имя класса, значение - путь относительно корня сайта к файлу с классом
                'CMyClassName1' => '/path/cmyclassname1file.php',
                'CMyClassName2' => '/path/cmyclassname2file.php',
        )
);
```

Answer (score 1):

Я решил эту ошибку следующим образом:

При установке модуля вызываю *Loader::includeModule($this->MODULE_ID)*

```
function DoInstall()
    {
        ModuleManager::registerModule($this->MODULE_ID);

        if (Loader::includeModule($this->MODULE_ID))
        {
            $this->InstallDB();
            $this->InstallEvents();
            $this->InstallFiles();
        }
    }
```

в include.php

```
\Bitrix\Main\Loader::registerAutoLoadClasses('has.module',
    [
        '\Has\Module\Internals\ModuleTable' => 'lib/internals/moduletable.php'
    ]
);
```